# How to make strip (cuted package) work fine at the end of page with separated line?

Tags: two-column, cuted

When `strip` environment comes near to the end of the page, we have an ugly effect:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{report}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathtools, cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{strip}
\lipsum
\end{strip}
\end{document}
```

[image: photo]

Comment: Looks like a bug of the cuted package.

Comment: it seems the same to me too @KeksDose, but I hope someone find a workaround

Comment: Better describe what you want to achieve and why you do not use the multicol package.

Comment: You aren't bothered about half the text disappearing to Never Never Land, then? Only about the line's being ugly? The package is not designed for use with large amounts of single-column text including page breaks. It wants to be used 'in the middle' of two-column text i.e. so there's stuff after it in two-columns. As @KeksDose mentions, `multicol` does not have this restriction. It *is* designed for large chunks which need to break across pages, so should be ideally suited to your purpose.

Comment: I guess `cuted` is only intended to insert passages significantly shorter than a page. Still shouldn't happen.